# mysqltuner invalid login credentials with verified correct password

Tags: mysql, mysqltuner

I downloaded mysqltuner to use on my ubuntu server and no matter which user I attempt to login with, it responds that my credentials are invalid. I routinely log in as root with my root password and yet it will not recognize it. Does mysqltuner need to be saved in a specific location? do i need to specify 'root'@'something'? What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm having the same issue. I can't connect to localhost but I can connect to remote host with this:

> mysqltuner --host yourhostname --user youruser

Comment: It says "Performing tests" and after some minutes it is again " Attempted to use login credentials, but they were invalid"

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a little old, but maybe it can help someone

Connect with your user and just run `perl mysqltuner.pl` without specifying the `--host` flag as the localhost is the default host. and the mysqltuner will run without any error of login....

Answer (score 0):

READ FAQ: https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl

Question gets his response 
is Why does MySQLTuner keep asking me the login credentials for MySQL over and over?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

The script mysqltuner.pl works when I disabled, in the `my.cnf` or `my.ini` file, the line:

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```